# How to authenticate a google home user with the back-end server?

Tags: oauth-2.0, actions-on-google

We are trying to link the google home app with our back-end server. At the moment we can login to the google home app with a google account and send an access token to our own api. We can also login to our own services with a google account. But how can we verify who is sending the requests from the google home to connect both accounts.

Information received by google login from our server.

```
object(Google_Service_Oauth2_Userinfoplus)#48 (14) {
  ["internal_gapi_mappings":protected]=>array(3) {
    ["familyName"]=>string(11) "family_name"
    ["givenName"]=>string(10) "given_name"
    ["verifiedEmail"]=>string(14) "verified_email"
  }
  ["email"]=>NULL
  ["familyName"]=>string(6) "familyname"
  ["gender"]=>string(4) "male"
  ["givenName"]=>string(7) "givenname"
  ["hd"]=>NULL
  ["id"]=>string(21) "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  ["link"]=>string(45) "https://plus.google.com/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  ["locale"]=>string(2) "nl"
  ["name"]=>string(14) "firstname lastname"
  ["picture"]=>string(92) ""
  ["verifiedEmail"]=>NULL
  ["modelData":protected]=>array(2) {
    ["given_name"]=>string(7) ""
    ["family_name"]=>string(6) ""
  }
  ["processed":protected]=>array(0) {
  }
}
array(6) {
  ["access_token"]=>string(140) "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  ["expires_in"]=>int(3599)
  ["scope"]=>string(206) "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.language.read
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.agerange.read"
  ["token_type"]=>string(6) "Bearer"
  ["id_token"]=>string(1085) "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  ["created"]=>int(1534615815)
}
```

Post request from google home to the webhook

```
{  
 "user":{  
  "userId":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "accessToken":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "locale":"nl-NL",
  "lastSeen":"2018-10-15T14:17:23Z",
  "userStorage":"{\"data\":{}}"
  },
  "conversation":{  
  "conversationId":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "type":"ACTIVE",
  "conversationToken":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting an `accessToken` in the request to your webhook, then this is an access token that your OAuth2 server should have issued to the Assistant so it can act on your behalf. Presumably, you would use this token in your auth system to identify the user's account, but the exact method for doing so is up to you since it depends on the OAuth server you're using.

Since you're assuming a Google account, however, you can simplify things greatly by using [Google Sign in for Assistant](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in). This will give you an `idToken` instead which, when decoded and validated, will include their Google ID, which should match the `id` you get from their profile.

Comment: I also have a question about the user_id. Is the user_id always the same and can we use that as a reference to authenticate a user?

Comment: That sounds like a different issue, and I suggest asking it as a new StackOverflow question (being specific about which "user_id" you're talking about).